# como puedo ver una pagina desde mi telefono por wifi a un computador que tiene un servido lamp que esta conectado a la misma red wifi

Tags: php, aplicación-web, xampp, servidor, ip

no se si me explique bien en el titulo de la pregunta, pero acá doy mas detalle, para empezar aclaro que tengo un computador con linux instalado, y tengo un servidor local con xampp. como dije tanto mi PC como mi teléfono están conectados a la misma red wifi, a lo que quiero llegar es si es posible que pueda yo visualizar o interactuar con la pagina web o aplicación que realice con PHP en mi PC, accediendo desde mi teléfono ?.. saludos

Comment: debes ingresar por el ip de tu maquina!

Comment: Creo que estas confundiendo un concepto. No importa si es wifi, telefono, cable de red o lo que sea. La conexion a una pagina se hace via internet, y lo que tenes en tu pc es un servidor de paginas web y tiene una ruta (una ip) a donde acceder.

Comment: En una terminal de tu linux escribe `ip addr` para ver qué IP tiene. En tu teléfono usa esa IP como "host" al cual conectar desde el navegador. Si no conecta, verifica que realmente están en la misma subred (puedes ver la IP de tu teléfono en Ajustes->Conexiones->WiFi->Avanzado y al final de las opciones te sale junto con la dirección MAC. Por lo general, si las tres primeras cifras de la IP coinciden con las del linux, es que están en la misma subred.

Comment: @Bryro, eso hice ya! , pero resulta que si puedo "VER" la app en mi teléfono, lo que no se visualiza son sus estilos. a que se debe eso?

Comment: @gbianchi si ya acabe de consultar la ip de la maquina

Comment: puede que la url este mal si le colocaleste como localhost/css/index.css

Comment: @abulafia mi teléfono esta en la misma red, ya consulte la IP del computador con el comando que me dices y sale esto 192.168.0.8/24

Comment: @Bryro accedí desde mi teléfono así : 192.168.0.8/mi-proyecto

Comment: si tienes razón @Bryro porque en mi lógica para acceder a la ruta coloque fue así como dices

Comment: @CristhianMolina debes colocar la de la maquina en vez de localhost/

Comment: @Bryro la tengo así : 192.168.0.8/mi-proyecto/public/main.css y no me funciona

Comment: http://192.168.0.8/mi-proyecto/public/main.css

Comment: acabo de comprobar que esa ruta desde mi teléfono si se puede ver, pero en el html no se logar ver de la cual esta asi
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="192.168.0.8/mi-proyecto/public/main.css">

Comment: Si quieres ver cómo quedaría el diseño, la funcionalidad, etc. de tu aplicación web, puedes instalarte una extensión para Chrome llamada `Mobile/Responsive Web Design Tester`. En ella podrás simular tu web en cualquier móvil.